# How can I use multiple monitors with a remote emacs session?

Tags: ssh

I am running a tmux session on a server where I do my development work (this is where I run emacs). I have two monitors - how do I use both of them with the same emacs session? If I join the same tmux session, the monitors just mirror each other. If I am not in the same tmux session (and by extension a different emacs session) I will have to reread from disk everytime a file gets updated, and there can be differences between the different working versions of files. Any thoughts on how to use both monitors here?

Comment: Not sure if I follow, but is this question about Emacs or tmux?  You might want to look at [emacsclient](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start two tmux sessions. In one you run an Emacs and start the "Emacs server" using `M-x emacs-server RET`. In the other you can run `emacsclient -nw`, this will create a second tty frame.

In fact, you can use `emacsclient -nw` to connect to a graphical Emacs, in case one in running on the machine.

Comment: Is there a way to do that in the same tmux session? Should I care if it is in the same tmux session?

Comment: Of course, you can use the same tmux session on both monitors. Then you can start Emacs in one tmux window (or pane, I never remember the correct terminology) and `emacsclient` in another.

Comment: when i attach to the same tmux session, it just mirrors the other monitor - is the some other command i should use?

Comment: You have to run Emacs in one tmux window and `emacsclient` in another, and display then on the different monitors.

Comment: sorry, still not following. the steps I was taking were 1. open terminal in left window, ssh and tmux attach 2. open terminal in right window ssh, and tmux attach. When I do that they are mirrrored, so I can't do separate things like only open emacs in one window and emacsclient in the other as the commands are mirrored

Comment: You will need to create a second `tmux` window using `<PREFIX>-c`, and show one tmux window in each terminal. In fact, you don't need `tmux` at all to get Emacs up and running on two monitors.

Comment: was looking at this question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24274/attach-to-different-windows-in-session, seems I need to make another tmux session . So back at square one, make two tmux sessions. Thanks for your help!